# How can I disable and even remove the option of EnterFullScreen in View menu in macOS in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I created a HelloWorld macOS SwiftUI project and I am seeing the option of **EnterFullScreen** in **View** menu, so how can I remove this option and disable it from bace in SwiftUI?

```swift
@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Joakim's answer about using UserDefaults is probably the cleanest way.  You *can* filter it out by resorting directly to AppKit, but you have to make your own subclass of `NSMenu`, and then intercept it in the `insertItem` method, and you have to do it for both the View and Window menus (because if macOS can't insert it in View, it inserts in Window).   I have to do that in a Swift package I wrote to manage the main menu in a SwiftUI-like way, not so much to remove it, but to ensure that it's always at the end after dynamically populating the menu.

Comment: And unfortunately, you can't just filter it once, but rather continually, because macOS inserts it every time you open the menu (unlike `Start Dictation` and `Emoji and Symbols` in the Edit menu, which it inserts once when the Edit menu is created).  If Joakim's answer works for you, do that.  If not, just post a comment, and I'll try to find some time to put an answer about how to filter it out, but while it's not that hard, it's not a trivial amount of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this using `UserDefaults` by setting the key "NSFullScreenMenuItemEverywhere" to false as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52171612/9223839) but if you do it in `applicationWillFinishLaunching` as in that answer it will be too late to take effect so move it to the `init()` in your App struct

```
init() {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "NSFullScreenMenuItemEverywhere")
}
```

If you rather use the AppStorage property wrapper for this it could look like this

```
@AppStorage("NSFullScreenMenuItemEverywhere") var fullScreenEnabled = false

init() {
     fullScreenEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define a maximum size for your view, and then tell the window group to use the content size as a limit for your window's sizing.

For example:

```swift
struct TestApp: App {
      var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
              .frame(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 500)
        }
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
    }
}
```

As the window cannot now go above the size you've set, it's ineligible to be a full-screen window and SwiftUI automatically disables the option in the menu.

After a little bit of experimentation, it seems `.windowResizability(.contentSize)` requires a maximum view size that's smaller than the screen – if you supply values that are larger than the current screen resolution the full screen option gets re-enabled.

You can of course omit a maximum, in which case the window will be a fixed size based on the contents.

Comment: You are missing the point, the question is about the _menu item_ for full screen

Comment: That code disables the menu item.

Comment: They're not necessarily that strange – if a window can't go full screen, then there's presumably some maximum size that it _can_ go. And it's a principle that can be applied to a single WindowGroup, which might be useful for larger apps that have more than one.